# How do I wrap a very long line of text in a GWT label?

Tags: gwt, label, word-wrap

This is an extract of my code at the moment:

```
VerticalPanel mainPanel = new VerticalPanel();
RootPanel.get("messages").add(mainPanel);

HorizontalPanel tempPanel = new HorizontalPanel();
tempPanel.setSize("100px", "200px");

Label content = new Label("AAAveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryverylongtextZZZ");
content.setWidth("50px");
content.setWordWrap(true);

tempPanel.add(content);
mainPanel.add(tempPanel);
```

The label displays but it does not wrap.
If I insert a space it seems that word wrap works, but I guess I want character wrap.
Any ideas?

I do not want a horizontal scrollbar.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is really more of a CSS question, than a GWT question.  `setWordWrap()` is typically used to *un*-set word wrap on a div -- word wrapping (on whitespace) is the default.

What you want to do is add some CSS to the Label that says `{ word-wrap: break-word; }`

More information [here](http://www.css3.com/css-word-wrap/).

Answer (score 2):

I used `label.setStyleAttribute("whiteSpace", "normal");`